# How to determine if an object is in an array based on property value / how to use selectors?

Tags: objective-c

I'm still trying to get my head around how selectors and dynamic typing work in objective c.  I'm essentially trying to implement this method (shown below in python/pseudocode, same thing really :P)

```
def isInArray(value, array, test):
    for item in array:
        if test(item) == value:
            return True
    return False

test = lambda obj: obj.property
```

My intended objective-c code was:

```
+ (BOOL)value:(id)value:
    isInArray:(NSMutableArray *)array 
usingSelector:(SEL)selector {
    for (id item in array) {
        if (value == [item selector]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

However, this throws a compile error, complaining that I"m comparing two pointer types (id and SEL) in the if statement.

Shouldn't that if statement be comparing the object value with the object returned from running SEL selector on the object arritem?  In other words, why does it think that it's comparing an object with a SEL (I don't see what would be returning a SEL there)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout [`performSelector`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html) in `NSObject`. The conditional would look like,

```
if (value == [item performSelector:selector])
```

By using [`Key Value Coding`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/valueForKeyPath%3a) (KVC), your code could become even simpler. Say you have an array named `people`, where each person is an object of the class `Person`. A `Person` has `firstName` and `lastName` properties, and you want to get all people whose first name matches `"John"` from the `people` array. You could get an array of all first names, and then lookup the name `"John"` in that array.

```
NSArray *firstNames = [people valueForKey:@"firstName"];
if ([firstNames containsObject:@"John"]) {
  ..
}
```

Even though we're using `valueForKey`, it's actually making a call to the `firstName` method, and not directly accessing the value.

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was missing something obvious!

Answer (score 0):

at least one mistake I see in method definition. There are no need to add colon after variable name (in your case `value`). And you should use `performSelector:` to make object check with your selector.

```
+ (BOOL)value:(id)value
    isInArray:(NSMutableArray *)array 
usingSelector:(SEL)selector {
    for (id item in array) {
        if ([item performSelector:selector] == value) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

In some cases you will need use `isEqualTo:` or `isEqualToString:` (if you work with strings) instead of `==` because `==` will return true if it's the same object.

Also, if you will need just check presence of some object in NSArray, than you could use `containsObject:` (return true if it is) and `indexOfObjectPassingTest:` (return index of object or 'NSNotFound')

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was after :)  I was trying to avoid using indexOfObjectPassingTest (it just seems so convoluted).  What do you mean about == vs isEqualTo?  I thought == was by value for built-in basic types (strings etc) and by reference for NSObjects by default.  Oh and no idea how the colon crept in tehre :P

Comment: see this my small example: https://gist.github.com/1569913 I test there `isEqual:`, `isEqualToArray:` methods and `==` operator on two arrays with the same objects. As you can see from that my example `isEqual:` works the same as `isEqualToArray:` and I suppose it overridden in NSArray class to calling `isEqualToArray:`. And if both arrays have the same objects, than theirs comparison with this two methods return true, but if you use `==` operator you will get false because it's two different objects in memory. Hope it helps you ;)

Comment: Yep, thanks.  They work backwards compared to what I'm used to, but it's logical enough now that I know :)